# Symfony2: Where to put request to db build with QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, structure, query-builder

I am new by using Symfony and I am a bit confused concerning the structure. I made a custom query with the queryBuilder but I don't really know where to put this piece of code. It work inside the controller but I don't like to have interaction with db there. So I though to put it inside an entity repository but it's really limited and I am not able to use it for my case. This query make a request with join and filter by multiple column.

So where could I put this code?

Edit1:

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EgCBGEBundle:portfoliohistory_pfh');
    $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('pfh');
    $queryBuilder->innerJoin('pfh.portfolio', 'pfo', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'pfh.id_pfo = pfo.id_pfo');
    $queryBuilder->where('pfh.scenario = :scenario')
                 ->andWhere('pfh.measure_catalogue = :measureCatalogue')
                 ->andWhere('pfh.portfolio IN ('.$subs.')')
                 ->andWhere('pfh.date = :date')
                 ->setParameter('scenario', $scenario)
                 ->setParameter('measureCatalogue', $type)
                 ->setParameter('date', $date)
                 ->groupBy('pfh.portfolio, pfh.id') // , pfo.id
                 //->orderBy('pfo.id', 'ASC')
                 ->setMaxResults(5);
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Post your code, and i'll try to understand why you can't put it in your Repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to your custom repository: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories

```
Class YourEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   public function findMyQuery($scenario, $type, $date){

     $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('pfh');
     $queryBuilder->innerJoin('pfh.portfolio', 'pfo', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'pfh.id_pfo = pfo.id_pfo');
     $queryBuilder->where('pfh.scenario = :scenario')
             ->andWhere('pfh.measure_catalogue = :measureCatalogue')
             ->andWhere('pfh.portfolio IN ('.$subs.')')
             ->andWhere('pfh.date = :date')
             ->setParameter('scenario', $scenario)
             ->setParameter('measureCatalogue', $type)
             ->setParameter('date', $date)
             ->groupBy('pfh.portfolio, pfh.id') // , pfo.id
             //->orderBy('pfo.id', 'ASC')
             ->setMaxResults(5);
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

And don't forget to include it in your entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\entity(repositoryClass="My\Bundle\Entity\YourEntityRepository ")
 */
```

In your controller

```
$results= $em->getRepository('My\Bundle\Entity\YourEntity')->findMyQuery($scenario, $type, $date);
```

Comment: I forgot to add the repositoryClass in the config file :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should put it in your repository

```
class YourEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   public function findItWithACustomQuery($some_params){

     $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('pfh');
     $queryBuilder->innerJoin('pfh.portfolio', 'pfo', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'pfh.id_pfo = pfo.id_pfo');
     $queryBuilder->where('pfh.scenario = :scenario')
             ->andWhere('pfh.measure_catalogue = :measureCatalogue')
             ->andWhere('pfh.portfolio IN ('.$subs.')')
             ->andWhere('pfh.date = :date')
             ->setParameter('scenario', $scenario)
             ->setParameter('measureCatalogue', $type)
             ->setParameter('date', $date)
             ->groupBy('pfh.portfolio, pfh.id') // , pfo.id
             //->orderBy('pfo.id', 'ASC')
             ->setMaxResults(5);
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Then you just call it in your controller or service by

```
$em->getRepository('YourEntityBundle:YourEntity')->findItWithACustomQuery($params);
```

Comment: I will give a try, I think it was not working because I was using findBy and not findItWith. My bad, I should have read better the documentation!

Comment: I get the following error: Undefined method 'findItWithACustomQuery'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

Comment: you can call it anything, findBySexualDesire, findThisStupidArticle or checkThisOut should works ;)

Comment: If I call it findBySexualDesire, it said me that the column doesn't exist :(

Comment: maybe this one doesn't work ^^ findBy and FindOneBy have some aliases.

Comment: Follow this small section of the doctrine2 docs: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories

Answer (score 0):

QueryBuilder is part of Doctrine. You can use it in your controller or in a custom class.
Here is a part of the official doc [http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html)

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html

And an example : http://drafts.easybib.com/post/44139111915/taiming-repository-classes-in-doctrine-with-the